# What statistical software does NOT provide for Classification and Regression models

Tags: cart, software

Appended is a list (as far as I can tell) of statistical software that DOES provide for use of Classification and Regression Tree (CART) models.  Some have the CART as a trivial case of things like random-forests or gradient boosted machines.

What I want to know is, outside of these, what software does NOT provide for CART models.

**EDIT:**

The proprietary software used internally here (not Excel) does not support CART models.  I am making a business case that, when performing ML tasks we need to have software that is capable.  I really am looking for a lack of only this feature.  I am looking for MAINSTREAM statistics GENERAL PURPOSE DATA ANALYSIS packages whose - something likely currently being used by a fortune 500 company to generate actionable results given input information.  I am not looking for every mom-and-pop software package.

I am not asking if anyone could hand-code it in Haskell or Cobol.  I'm asking if it is ALREADY in a PACKAGE for the software.  R has a half-dozen packages.  MatLab has one or two, but it requires a proprietary toolbox.

**Outside of the Excel answer - I cannot think of or find a serious package not already accounted for.**

If I made a mistake or omission here, please let me know.

As always, suggestions, corrections, comments and feedback are solicited.

Here is my best shot at an exhaustive list of **Mainstream/production statistics** software with established **built-in** CART implementations:

- (MatLab)
  http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/classification-trees-and-regression-trees.html
- (Python) http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html
- (R)    http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html
- (JMP)    http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Partition_Method.shtml
- (Weka/RapidMiner)
  http://jcsites.juniata.edu/faculty/rhodes/ida/dmcloser.html
- (Mahout/Hadoop)
  https://mahout.apache.org/users/classification/partial-implementation.html
- (Mathematica)
  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KaryTree.html?q=KaryTree&lang=en
- (h2o) http://docs.h2o.ai/datascience/gbm.html
- (openCV)    http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/decision_trees.html
- (KNIME) https://www.knime.org/files/nodedetails/_labs_treeensemble_Tree_Ensemble_Learner_Regression_.html
- (MS Azure ML)
  https://projectbotticelli.com/knowledge/brief-introduction-to-microsoft-azure-ml
- (Statistica)
  http://www.statsoft.com/Textbook/Classification-and-Regression-Trees
- (IBM SPSS)
  http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/en/spss-decision-trees
- (Orange)
  http://orange.biolab.si/docs/latest/reference/rst/Orange.classification.tree.html

Comment: I don't know if there is a point in making a list of software that does *not* do something. Do you *really* want to list all the "t-test calculators" that float around the web in thousands..?

Comment: @Tim - see the updated (EDIT) section.

Comment: Minitab, AFAIK, doesn't currently implement any tree-based methods.

Comment: List-of-lists questions are generally not on topic here.  One useful way to present your research would be in our meta thread on [support for software](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software).

Comment: And you might want to add Stata & PASW Modeller (Clementine) to your list of software that *do* implement them.

Comment: @EngrStudent - "mainstream" also does *not* make much sens still: Gephi is a "mainstream" software for social network analysis, Stan is "mainstream" for Bayesian estimation, Ggplot is "mainstream" for plotting - all of them are "mainstream" and "statistical" while you won't even expect cart to be implemented in them. It is like asking about "all mainstream politicians that don't have blue eyes": the answer depends on (a) what "mainstream" is and (b) is possibly unlimited.

Comment: @Tim: "General purpose" was perhaps an additional, unstated, criterion.

Comment: @Scortchi - it was just an example, what I argue is that there is possibly more unstated criteria that made question stated like this too broad.

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, whenever you're looking for software without a particular function, Excel is a good place to start.

Comment: Lol.  This is a beautiful answer.